# Android WebView completely disrespecting UI layout

Tags: java, android, webkit, webview

this is driving me nuts and causing me to pull so much hair, I actually ran out of hair and started hurting random people.

I have a UI design in which the WebView is supposed to be to the north, vertically of course, and a bar or line of buttons at the south. So the majority of the design is the WebView, and at the bottom some of the buttons.

The webview is used to load some images from the world wide holy web, and it seems since the images are quite wide and long, the webview just completely swallows the buttons at the bottom, so the design only shows the Webview and none of the buttons at the bottom bar.

I have tried many many things, from nested LinearLayouts to TableLayouts and TableRows.

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should post your xml file, I would either use a linear layout and give them both no height and a weight, or better yet a relative layout the webview should have alignParentTop set to true and also have the attribute above set to your button id.

Comment: Your RelativeLayout method worked, but only after I also added the property android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to the button row.

Thanks!